# Azure App Services API - Domains - Create Or Update - domain.Properties.Consent has an invalid value. Domain Transfer

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Here is my issue. I've been trying to transfer a domain to Azure. 
I've tried to utilize Microsoft's tool online: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/domains/createorupdate#code-try-0

But I keep getting:

> The parameter domain.Properties.Consent has an invalid value.

```
{
 "location": "global",
 "properties": {
  "consent": {
   "agreementKeys": ["DNTA","DNPA"],
   "agreedBy": "163.xxx.29.xxx",
   "agreedAt": "2019-07-30T01:02:38"
  },
  "contactAdmin": {...},
  "contactBilling": {...},
  "contactRegistrant": {...},
  "contactTech": {...},
  "privacy": false,
  "autoRenew": true,
  "authCode": "201\\S4$04BGK4G9E"
 }
}
```

There is a couple of people working on this and I hope we didn't step on each others toes. 
I've done this before and haven't received a message like this before.
Thanks for any ones help.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am getting this same error.

Comment: Never figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I always get http 500 error.
Change privacy to true,  I got http 200.

Comment: After setting the privacy to true I now get an http 500.